# Keep annotated clutter away from Domain Model

Tags: java, annotations, dependencies

I'm in the situation where I have a Domain Model that is clean. By clean I mean it's just a collection of private properties and getter and setters. I guess that's what's ment by the Anemic Data Model.

This model is interchangeable with other applications (can be shared with other application code) without pulling in extra dependencies.

This model needs to be serialized to different data formats. For this I can use a wide range of annotations that greatly simplify my life.

Only they pull in an extra set of dependencies in all the projects that will share the domain model.
I've read it's not advised to clutter the domain model for such reasons and I could possibly land in a Jar Hell.

I could write a wrapper that is annotated and pass in the domain model in the constructor and copy all the properties over to the annotated model. This way I can happily use annotations while keeping a clean Domain Model that will not enforce any extra dependencies.

This is not specifically about serializing your data model but about adding extra functionality (for example through annotations) in your Domain Model that enforces new dependencies.

How do you handle such use cases what's a safe way to handle this without having to fear Jar Hell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to use the annotations at compile time.
If the annotation classes are not available at runtime they will simply not exist.

E.g. if the client code calls AnnotatedElement.getAnnotations() on a
domain model class and the annotations it was compiled with are not available in the class path they will not be returned.

If you use maven you should declare the annotation dependencies with scope optional.
Optional dependencies will not be included in the client.
Thus they are only available if the client declares them.

For example:

If Proj-A has a optional dependency ( ?-> ) on Proj-B

```
 Proj-A ?-> Proj-B
```

and a Proj-X references Proj-A as a compile dependency it will not get the optional dependency Proj-B.

```
 Proj-X -> Proj-A
```

because transitive dependency resolution ends on an optional dependency.

Expect that you have the following annotation in a jar file called `annotations.jar`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ARuntimeAnnotation {

}
```

and you have the following model class contained in a `model.jar`

```
@ARuntimeAnnotation
public class Model {

}
```

and the `model.jar` has a dependency to the `annotations.jar` because it needs it to compile.

```
<depdendency>
       <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
       <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
       <scope>optional</scope>
 </dependency>
```

If this dependency is optional it will not be automatically become a transitive dependency of someone how only has a dependency on the `model.jar`.

Now a client wants to use the `Model` class. Thus it has a dependency to `model.jar`.

```
 <depdendency>
       <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
       <artifactId>model</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

If the client also wants to see the annotation `ARuntimeAnnotation` it must also include the
annotations.jar as a dependency, because it is optional.

If the client does not include dependency on the annotations.jar the following call will return an empty array:

```
 Model.class.getAnnotations(); // will be empty if the annotations.jar is not available at runtime
```

Comment: But I could still end up in dependency hell at compile time , not ?

Comment: As far as I understood your question: You have a domain jar. The domain jar classes have a lot of different annotations. The annotations are used by different clients, but each client only uses a subset. E.g JAXB, JPA annotations or whatever. Now you want to prevent each client from getting all annotation dependencies?

Comment: Yes that's true. 
What about annotations that have a RetentionPolicy set to RUNTIME ?

Comment: The RetentionPolicy RUNTIME means that they will be compiled into the byecode. But if the annotation class is not available at runtime you will not get it. If you set the RetentionPolicy to SOURCE the annotations will not be included in the bytecode. Thus they will never be available at runtime even when the annotations classes are available.

Comment: So I could use any annotation I like and next annotate my Domain Model class with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) to enforce dependency at Compile time but not at Runtime ?

Comment: No, that was not what I mean. You can use any annotation on your domain model. But if the library that contains the annotation is not available at runtime you will not get these annotations.